# Is it possible to analyze the return value of a program?

Tags: c++, c

Is it possible to analyze the return value of a `main` program?

For example:

```
int main() {    
    //stuff
    return something;
}
```

Is there a way to check what value is going to be "`something`" and change it?
For example, my program is expected to `return 3;`

Could there be a way to check if `something` returns 3, and if this is not true, change it to 3 and then return 3?

Comment: Check from where? Change it where? *Why* change it?

Comment: You can get value by `./myprog; echo $?`. and how you would like to change value?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Get the value from the return of Main (Please, learn to read) and change it there .-. I got the answers below. For example `exit 3`
And BECAUSE it's my program :P

Comment: What I mean is, what program or system should monitor the return value from your program? And what program or system should change the return value? But the most important question is still *why*? (Related reading: [What is the XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: But JoachimPileborg is completely right. What `main` happens to return is dependent on the hosting environment (e.g. the operating system where your program is running). It is not the same on Linux and on some simple monitor running on the bare metal.

Comment: @user we can all read, but your question is very unclear

Comment: Jajaja I hope I don't become a silly antisocial guy like all of you later... As I can see, you just want to see burn the noobs because you all feel "superior" when someone ask somthing lol.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just wrap the program.  A simple way would be to write a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

myprogram "$@" # pass any args we got
exit 3
```

Comment: This is a solution for unix-like environments (in case that was not clear).

Answer (score 3):

It is actually operating system specific. On Posix and Linux, read about [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25299892/841108) (to a somehow related question) which gives useful references. For Linux, read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (most of it is relevant for Posix systems like Linux and MacOSX).

Your program might run in some limited environment like a monitor running on the bare metal (or some small realtime system like [Vxorks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VxWorks)). Then the return code of `main` might have a different meaning, and perhaps could not be easily tested or changed.

Notice that the return code of `main` is called the [exit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit.2.html) code -at least on Posix systems-. On Linux, it has only one byte. If `main` is returning 1000, the exit code would be `1000&0xff` i.e. 232.

AFAIK, standard C or C++ knows only about `EXIT_SUCCESS` (which should be 0) and `EXIT_FAILURE` (which is 1 on Linux) from `<stdlib.h>`. Other values like 3 have an implementation specific meaning.